# Phabricator (maniphest) custom field issue

Tags: project-management, phabricator, bug-tracker, maniphest

I am trying to add custom fields to Phabricator, particularly Maniphest, and even the example given in the documentation does not work (there is an open quote in it, but even correcting that still does not help.
I have made sure that the config is a valid JSON, using Firefox's console and I have trimmed all tabs and spaces and yet it does not accept it. Any idea what am I doing wrong or if it is a bug? If so, is there a workaround?

Comment: Can you post it here for us to help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the documentation. The example also had an incorrect trailing comma at the end. The best way to report bugs to us is to file them against the upstream, here:

https://secure.phabricator.com/maniphest/task/create/